# Installed OpenVPN server on rooted Android, but routing is not working

Tags: openvpn

I wanted to install OpenVPN server on rooted Android and [found a solution on StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213848/can-we-make-a-vpn-server-run-on-android/248007). I rooted my phone, installed Linux Deploy, installed Ubuntu in it and compiled latest OpenVPN server and EasyRSA.

When I start OpenVPN server on my phone and I can connect to it with a client, but I can't ping anything but myself. Below is my server configuration (same configuration works fine if I set it up on real Ubuntu server):

```
# server 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0 
# push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
# topology subnet 
# push "topology subnet"
# push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80" 
# push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"
# duplicate-cn
# data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC'
# keepalive 10 120 
# persist-key 
# persist-tun 
# explicit-exit-notify 1
# log-append /var/log/openvpn.log 
# verb 3
```

I haven't installed iptables or ufw so that's not a problem.
My router LAN ip address is 192.168.2.1 and my telephone ip address is 192.168.2.28 (wlan0).
My OpenVPN server is on 10.10.1.1 (tun0) address and my OpenVPN client gets 10.10.1.2.

**On the StackExchange link I posted, guy said that Android ignores main table at all, so we should create custom rules and insert routes.**

Without adding any routes to server, I can't even ping 10.10.1.1 from my client, but when I add `sudo ip route add 10.10.1.0/24 dev tun0 table 5000` ping started working for 10.10.1.1 and 192.168.2.28 and that's it, I can't get to 192.168.2.1 or any further.

I tried adding `sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0 table 5000` but nothing changes.

I even tried `sudo ip route add default dev wlan0 table 5000`, but when I add that, I can't even connect from my client to my server any more.

Anyone have any idea how can I fix this?